# Ranking the "Flexibility" of Markov Chains?

Tags: probability, statistics

At first glance, Semi Markov Processes seem to not take into consideration the past history of the process when deciding which state will be visited next - on the other hand, Continuous Markov Processes seem capable of taking into consideration the past history of the process when deciding which state will be visited next.

Provided I have understood this correctly - in my opinion, Continuous Time Markov Processes seem in a certain way to offer a higher level of flexibility, as many real-world applications (e.g. disease progression) are likely dependent on longer term histories of the Markov Process.

I have heard that one of the advantages of the Semi Markov Process is that the "holding times" (i.e. "sojourn times") do not need to be Exponentially Distributed, whereas in a Continuous Time Markov Process the "holding times" need to be Exponentially Distributed - however, using a Inhomogeneous Continuous Time Markov Chain, the holding times also do not need to be Exponentially Distributed.

**Therefore, it appears to me that  (Inhomogeneous) Continuous Time Markov Chain offers more modelling flexibility when compared to a Semi Markov Process.**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the current state of a Semi Markov Processes (SMP), as well as in the current state of a Continuous Markov Processes (CTMC), you can encode as much information as you wish. Therefore, both are conditionally independent of the past, given the current state. In the particular case of SMP, you also need to know the residual time in the current state in order to determine the future of the process (in the case of CTMC, the current state suffices for all purposes).

In an SMP, the holding times do not need to be exponentially distributed.  However, they are still very easy to treat.  Indeed, the steady state probability, for instance, is given by

$$\pi_i=\frac{\tilde{\pi}_i h_i}{\sum \tilde{\pi}_j h_j}$$

where $h_j$ is the mean holding time at state $j$, and $\tilde{\pi}_i$ is the fraction of visits to state $i$, according to the subsumed Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC).

In any case, you do not take into consideration the past history of the process when deciding which state will be visited next.

In both cases, you are capable of taking into consideration the past history of the process when deciding which state will be visited next, as far as you encode (relevant) past history inside the current state, for instance, using an $n$ order Markov process (see https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/a6m33bin/markov-chains-2.pdf)

Now, Inhomogeneous Continuous Time Markov Chain offers more modelling flexibility when compared to a Semi Markov Process.  However, they are much more complex to deal with.  The rates of the process depend on time.  In many situations, you do not need that because

- you can divide time into windows, and in each window you assume that the process is homogeneous
- you may capture the inhomogeneous behavior through state variables as opposed to a full-fledge inhomogeneous chain

Comment: @ Daniel S. : Thank you so much for your answer! Do you know about modelling markov chains in real life? I posted a question here - can you please take a look at it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594033/markov-chains-from-theory-to-application thank you so much!

Comment: I like the answer that you already have there! Did you follow it?

Comment: Daniel S: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I saw it - I liked it! I am hoping that more people will reply and provide more answers! please comment if you would like to add anything!